# Spring Boot Admin - Running in Docker Swarm weirdly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, swarm, spring-boot-admin

I am running multiple Spring-Boot servers all connected to a Spring Boot Admin instance.  Everything is running  in the same Docker Swarm.

Spring Boot Admin keeps reporting on these "fake" instances that pop up and die.  They are up for 1 second and then become unresponsive.  When I clear them, they come back.  The details for that instance show this error:

```
Fetching live health status failed. This is the last known information.

Request failed with status code 502
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

This is the same for all my APIs.  This is causing us to get an inaccurate health reading of our services.  How can I get Admin to stop reporting on these non-existant containers ?

I've looked in all my nodes and can't find any containers (running or stopped) that match the unresponsive containers that Admin is reporting.